# cat multiple files in separate directories file1 file2 file3....file100 using loop in bash script

Tags: bash, loops, cat

I have several files in multiple directories like in directory 1/file1 2/file2 3/file3......100/file100. I want to cat all those files to a single file using loop over index in bash script. Is there easy loop for doing so?

Thanks,

Comment: So you want `cat */file*`?

Comment: the 100 dirs/files follow some rule or they are completely random? E.g. `dir{ID}/file{ID}`?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes all the files follow dir1/file1, dir2/file2, dir3/file3.....dir100/file100. That is why I want a looping in bash script instead of doing  cat dir1/file1 dir2/file2 ... dir100/file100 > file

Comment: Ah, do you want to append them in numerical order, instead of `1 10 2 20 3 ...` ? Easiest to rename them all correctly with leadning zeros `001` etc. Otherwise just `for dir in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 .... 100 ; do cat $dir/* ; done > outFile`. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

```
seq 100 | sed 's:.*:dir&/file&:' | xargs cat
```

- `seq 100` generates list of numbers from `1` to `100`
- `sed`

  - `s` substitutes
  - `:` separates parts of the command
  - `.*` the whole line
  - `:` separator. Usually `/` is used, but it's used in replacement string.
  - `dir&/file&` by `dir<whole line>/file<whole line>`
  - `:` separator
  - so it generates list of `dir1/file1` ... `dir100/file100`
- `xargs` - pass input as arguments to ...

  - `cat` - so it will execute `cat dir1/file1 dir2/file2 ... dir100/file100`.

Answer (score 2):

This code should do the trick;

```
for((i=1;i<=`ls -l | wc -l`;i++)); do cat dir${i}/file${i} >> output; done
```

Comment: I want cat should work in serial order. I mean cat should work like "cat dir1/file1 dir2/file2 dir3/file3 > newfile" so that in the newfile contains files in the order of file1file2file3....

Comment: @whoami are dir1, dir2, file1 and file2 actual names of the files and directory?

Comment: dir1, dir2 are the directories whithin which there are files named file1 file2 respectively

Comment: I just tried following one of yours suggestions and it looks like works.                     for ((i=1;i<=54;i++));
do
cat ./$i/cartkpt$i;
done > CARTKPT

Answer (score 1):

I made an example of what you're describing about your directory structure and files. Create directories and files with It's own content.

```
for ((i=1;i<=100;i++)); do 
  mkdir "$i" && touch "$i/file$i" && echo content of "$(pwd) $i" > "$i/file$i"
done
```

Check the created directories.

```
ls */*

ls */* | sort -n
```

If you see that the directories and files are created then proceed to the next step.

This solution does not involve any external command from the shell except of course cat :-)

Now we can check the contents of each files using bash syntax.

```
i=1
while [[ -e "$i" ]]; do
  cat "$i"/*
  ((i++))
done
```

This code was tested in dash.

```
i=1
while [ -e "$i" ]; do
  cat "$i"/*
  i=$((i+1))
done
```

Just add the redirection of the output to the file after the done.
You can add some more test if you like see `help test`

One more thing :-), you can just check the contents using `tail` and brace `expansion`

```
tail -n +1 {1..100}/*
```

Using `cat` also you can redirect the output already, just remember `brace expansion` is bash3+ feature/syntax.

```
cat {1..100}/*
```